# Regex - Get number that is 10 or 11 digits long only

Tags: php, regex, search

So, I've written a Regex equation to fetch UK phone numbers, it looks like this:

```
[(]*\d{3}[)]*\s*[.\-\s]*\d{3}[.\-\s]*\d{4}
```

It captures phone numbers perfectly, however if I provide a list which includes a number longer than 11 digits `etc: 01234567891011121314`, it will fetch the first 11 digits of that number.

I want to exclude this number altogether, rather than fetching the first 11 digits.

How can I do modify my expression to make this happen?

Thanks

EDIT:
For context:
The regex is used to fetch phone numbers from website source code, so the numbers can be surrounded by any character at all, I just want to capture those that don't have numbers surrounding them (making them over 11 digits)

EDIT 2:
Here's some source code for perspective:

```
<a class="social" href="https://www.facebook.com/pages/x-Ltd/194636607281565" target="_blank" title="Like us on facebook">
    <i class="icon icon-facebook"></i>
</a>
<p>123 Sesame Street</p>
<p>Brooklyn, NY</p>
<p>Contact Us: 0123 456 7890</p>
```

The phone number will not always have a `<` following it.

Comment: Try `'~\d{11,}(*SKIP)(?!)|[(]*\d{3}[)]*\s*[.\-\s]*\d{3}[.\-\s]*\d{4}~'`. However, this still needs adjusting. Please post exact requirements.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew - Context added to help improve answer

Comment: Can you provide a snippet of the source code?

Comment: @CameronRoe Some code added for more perspective

Comment: @RyanCastle: The task is very hard in fact. I suggest trying a series of regexes to see if they help. 1) Start with word boundaries and adjusting limiting quantifier thresholds - [`[(]*\b\d{3,4}[)]*[.\s-]*\d{3}[.\s-]*\d{4}\b`](https://regex101.com/r/EZd05z/1). 2) If there are "serial numbers", try avoiding them with lookarounds - [`[(]*\b(?<!\d-)\d{3,4}[)]*[.\s-]*\d{3}[.\s-]*\d{4}\b(?!-\d)`](https://regex101.com/r/EZd05z/2). There may appear other edge cases, but only you  have the data, we can't provide a good valid answer.

Comment: Observations: 1. Your regex only matches 10 digits, where does 11 come into it? 2. You specify that something like `((((((((((000. .-.--.....000-.--..0000` can match, is that a real phone number ? 3. Given the allowed characters in between, what can be said of the characters surrounding the match, especially of the given _validation_, which is not real anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can utilize anchoring on the regular expression to make sure whatever is being matched only matches if it is exact, size and all. Adding a `^` to the start of the regular expression will indicate the regular expression must start at the start of the string and adding a `$` to the end of the regular expression will indicate the the regular expression must end at the end of the string.

So, try this:

`^[(]*\d{3}[)]*\s*[.\-\s]*\d{3}[.\-\s]*\d{4}$`

Comment: However, it is good for nothing as it won't "fetch" the numbers.

Comment: `(^[(]*\d{3}[)]*\s*[.\-\s]*\d{3}[.\-\s]*\d{4}$)` wrapping the expression in a capture group will allow you to grab the numbers that match the regular expression and won't do anything with the numbers that do not match them. I'm not sure how you want to fetch the numbers though, so my answer may still be insufficient for your ultimate task. You should edit your question and provide more detail as to what your use case is.

Comment: @CameronRoe - This has been done. More context has been added to improve clarity in the question